# Eigenvalue of the first-order reduced density matrix (1-RDM) and condensation of bosons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, bose-einstein-condensate

It is defined that `a system of identical bosons is said to be condensed, if  the largest eigenvalue of the first-order reduced density matrix (1-RDM) is of the order of the number of particles in the system`. Check [Phys. Rev. 104, 576 (1956)](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.104.576) and chapter 2 of [Many-Body Schrödinger Dynamics of Bose-Einstein Condensates](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-22866-7).

For a given wavefunction $\psi(r_{1},...,r_{N};t)$ of $\mathcal{N}$ identical spinless bosons with spatial coordinates $r_{i}$, the first-order reduced density matrix (1-RDM) is defined as
$$
\rho^{(1)}(r_{1},r^{'}_{1};t)=N\int\psi(r_{1},r_{2},...,r_{N};t)\psi^{*}(r^{'}_{1},r_{2},...,r_{N};t)dr_{2}dr_{3}...dr_{N}=\langle\psi(t)|\hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}(r{'}_{1})\hat{\Psi}(r_{1})|\psi(t)\rangle
$$

where $\hat{\Psi}(r)$ is the bosonic field operator and the wavefunctions are properly normalized $\langle\psi(t)|\psi(t)\rangle=1$. The first-order reduced density matrix can be regarded as the kernal of the operator
$$
\hat{\rho}^{(1)}=\mathcal{N}.{Tr}_{\mathcal{N}-1}[|\psi(t)\rangle\langle\psi(t)|]
$$

What exactly are the 1-RDM and its eigenvalues and how do I get a physical picture of it?

What is the physical meaning of the above statement based on the definition of the 1-RDM?

Comment: Note that for indistinguishable particles, the "first-order reduced density matrix" typically refers to the matrix $M$ with elements $M_{ij}=\langle a^\dagger_i a_j\rangle$.

Comment: BTW, would help if you could focus your question more.  As it stands, it is very broad (and not very clear).

Comment: Closely related (?) question (though with no answer): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110371

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I have edited the actual question.please check.

Comment: I'm afraid that while you have added definitions, the question as such is still quite unclear.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I understand the meaning of a density matrix and the reduced density matrix. Ex. If we have a composite system, the density matrix $\rho=\sum P_{i}|\psi_{i}\rangle\langle\psi_{i}|$ defines the state of the system and its eigenvalue is the probability $P_{i}$ to be in the state $|\psi_{i}\rangle$. If we have a composite system of two qubits A and B, the state of qubit A is defined by the reduced density matrix $\rho^{A}$ which is the partial trace of $\rho^{AB}$ over B, i.e, $\rho^{A}=tr_{B}{(\rho^{AB})}=\langle0^{B}|\rho^{AB}|0^{B}\rangle+\langle1^{B}| \rho^{AB} |1^{B}\rangle$.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch is that correct ? But how do i get a first-order reduced density matrix and what does it actually says?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 1st order density matrix,
$$
\rho({\bf x}, {\bf x'}) = \langle \hat\psi^\dagger({\bf x'})\hat\psi({\bf x}) \rangle
$$
is a Hermitian operator since $\rho({\bf x}, {\bf x'})  = \rho^*({\bf x'}, {\bf x})$ and its diagonal entries,
$$
\rho({\bf x}, {\bf x}) = \langle \hat\psi^\dagger({\bf x})\hat\psi({\bf x}) \rangle = n({\bf x})
$$
give the number density of particles at location ${\bf x}$, such that 
$$
\int{d{\bf x} \;\rho({\bf x}, {\bf x})} \equiv \int{d{\bf x} \;n({\bf x})} = N
$$
is the (average) total number of particles in the system. Its orthonormal eigenfunctions, defined by
$$
\int{d{\bf x'} \rho({\bf x}, {\bf x'}) \phi_j({\bf x'})} = n_j \;\phi_j({\bf x})\\
\int{d{\bf x} \;\phi^*_j({\bf x})\phi_k({\bf x})} = \delta_{jk}\\
\sum_j{\phi^*_j({\bf x})\phi_j({\bf x'})} = \delta({\bf x} - {\bf x'})
$$
represent natural orbitals. The eigenvalues 
$$
n_j = \int{\int{d{\bf x}d{\bf x'} \;\phi^*_j({\bf x})\; \rho({\bf x}, {\bf x'})\; \phi_j({\bf x'})}}
$$
satisfy
$$
\sum_k{n_k} = \int{d{\bf x} \;n({\bf x})} = N
$$
and represent the occupation numbers of the natural orbitals.

In fact, if $a^\dagger_j$, $a_j$ are creation and annihilation operators of these orbitals, $[a_j, a^\dagger_k]=\delta_{jk}$, the field operators are expanded as
$$
\hat\psi({\bf x}) = \sum_j{\phi_j({\bf x})\;a_j}
$$
and we have
$$
\rho({\bf x}, {\bf x'}) = \sum_{jk}{\phi^*_j({\bf x'})\phi_k({\bf x}) \langle a^\dagger_j a_k \rangle}
$$
and 
$$
\rho_{jk} \equiv \langle a^\dagger_j a_k \rangle = \int{\int{d{\bf x}d{\bf x'} \phi^*_k({\bf x}) \rho({\bf x}, {\bf x'}) \phi_j({\bf x'})}} = \rho_{jj}\delta_{jk}\\
\rho_{jj} \equiv \langle a^\dagger_j a_j \rangle = n_j
$$
In the condensate state one orbital achieves a high occupation number $n_0 \sim N$, such that
$$
N = n_0 + \sum_{j\neq 0}{n_j}
$$
and the largest eigenvalue of $\rho({\bf x}, {\bf x'})$ becomes
$$
\rho_{00} = n_0
$$

See for example these lecture notes: "[Dynamics of Bose-Einstein Condensates in Trapped Atomic Gases at Finite Temperature](http://www.mpipks-dresden.mpg.de/~bec10/Lecture_1.pdf)"

Comment: Good answer.  It might be worth adding (w.r.t. to BEC) that if the largest eigenvalue $\eta_0$ is close (or proportional) to $N$, this means that the mode $a_0$ is occupied by $\eta_0$ particles, which corresponds to Bose-Einstein condensation.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Oy! I actually had in mind to add that and got distracted at the last moment. Thanks for bringing it up.